# Transpose list of dates based on both ID and Category in Excel or Access 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a very long list of three columns: ID, category and Date. The ID field is repeated for each different date, with a category of 1 to 3 assigned.

I really need to get these into a form I can analyse, where each ID has one row for each category, with the dates listed horizontally in date order (with column headings: 1st date, 2nd date, 3rd date, etc.)

There's about 2,000 rows, so if there's any way to do this without transposing each ID manually, it would be hugely appreciated.

I've tried pivot tables with no joy.

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

Answer (score -1):

If you sort by ID then by Category, then run it through a pivot chart in excel to aggregate the values.